# Shamir's Threshold Scheme (Theory Part, Need some help understanding a term that I can't find online)

Tags: secret-sharing

What does the max(S, n) part mean, and what am I supposed to do with it? I somewhat understand, but it is still confusing. I don't know what it exactly represents. Can you help me please?

[image: Shamir's Threshhold]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\max(a,b)$ is the largest of $a$ and $b$. That's also the meaning in many computer languages, e.g. [Python's `max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

Thus $p>\max(S,n)$ means: $p>S$ and $p>n$.

Comment: Thank you. This really clears it up.